# Hibernate optimistic locking for delete and insert queries

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I know hibernate optimistic locking with version column works for concurrent updates. Does it works when records are deleted and re-inserted concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work when you delete record because it uses version field from the row which will not be available when you delete that.